# Google script trigger stopped working with permission errors (Code:11:28)

Tags: google-apps-script

My calendar booking script stopped working in the past week. Checking the error logs, it seems that the trigger is still being fired but I am getting this error:

> Exception: The script doesn't have permission to perform that action. Required permission: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly || https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds) at unknown function

I have modified my appsscript.json to include the oauth for these three permissions but the script still doesn't work. Can anyone please advise? Thanks.

Contents of appsscript.json:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
    "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds"
  ],
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the script inside the Google Script editor, go to the Run menu and choose any function from the dropdown. This will prompt you to authorize the script again and the triggers will function again with the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it out be re-enabling permissions in the script file itself (by running the trigger script), and adding in additional oauthscopes as requested by the various errors. I previously did not need to do this, so have no idea why this happened in the last 4 days.